# How to Override `<base target="_blank">`

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have `<base target="_blank"/>` inserted into my html. I also have a search bar on my site as well but the results of the searches open in a new tab (because of the the `<base target="_blank"/>` line).

Is there a way to override `<base target="_blank"/>` just for the search results?

```
<form action="/search" method="get" class="sfm">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="{SearchQuery}" id="sf"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="sb"/>
</form>
```

Comment: why don't you use `target="_self"` attribute (right in the form)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms can take the `target` attribute as well! Setting it to `_self` should do what you desire:

```html
<form action="/search" target="_self" method="get" class="sfm">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="{SearchQuery}" id="sf"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="sb"/>
</form>
```